# Behavior of C flag in ARM SUBS instruction

Tags: assembly, arm64

Which flags are set for the instruction SUBS X1, X0, X0? Is it only Z flag or both Z and C flag?

Comment: SUBS affects all flags; AArch64 doesn't need partial-flag renaming to avoid stalls on common instructions!  Whether they're set or cleared depends on operands, obviously.  (With both sources the same, there's no carry-out so ARM / AArch64 set the `C` flag, IIRC.  It's inverted vs. how x86 sets CF.)

Comment: So, in the above example, Z and C flag will be set. Is that right?

Comment: I think so.  Try it in an AArch64 emulator if you want to check.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot.